# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: .net, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to get this SQL query to grab 1 more thing from another table. However, when I try and add it to the select, it is giving me an error - "Column 'OrderItem.orderItemValue' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Here is the original SQL query (in a stored procedure) which works fine:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE SP_InvoiceReports_CustProducts
@custIdent varchar(50) ,
@startDate datetime ,
@endDate datetime
AS
set @endDate = dateAdd(month, 1, @startDate)
SELECT product.styleDesc, product.styleRef , empCust.custName , productSize.sizeChartNme ,
    Sum(orderItemAudit.shipQuantity) as theShipment ,
    Sum(orderItemAudit.shipValue) as theCost
FROM orderItemAudit INNER JOIN
    orders ON 
    orderItemAudit.orderIdent = orders.orderIdent INNER JOIN
    OrderItem ON 
    orderItemAudit.orderItemIdent = OrderItem.orderItemIdent AND 
    orders.orderIdent = OrderItem.orderIdent INNER JOIN
    empCust ON 
    orders.custIdent = empCust.custIdent INNER JOIN
    product ON OrderItem.styleRef = product.styleRef  INNER JOIN
    productSize ON OrderItem.sizeChartIdent = productSize.sizeChartIdent 
WHERE empCust.custIdent = @custIdent
    and orderItemAudit.dateShipped >= @startDate
    and orderItemAudit.dateShipped <= @endDate
GROUP BY product.styleRef, product.styleDesc, empCust.custName, productSize.sizeChartNme
ORDER BY product.styleRef, product.styleDesc, empCust.custName, productSize.sizeChartNme
```

Here it is after I added what I want to select to it:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE SP_InvoiceReports_CustProducts
@custIdent varchar(50) ,
@startDate datetime ,
@endDate datetime
AS
set @endDate = dateAdd(month, 1, @startDate)
SELECT product.styleDesc, product.styleRef , empCust.custName , productSize.sizeChartNme , OrderItem.orderItemValue , 
    Sum(orderItemAudit.shipQuantity) as theShipment ,
    Sum(orderItemAudit.shipValue) as theCost
FROM orderItemAudit INNER JOIN
    orders ON 
    orderItemAudit.orderIdent = orders.orderIdent INNER JOIN
    OrderItem ON 
    orderItemAudit.orderItemIdent = OrderItem.orderItemIdent AND 
    orders.orderIdent = OrderItem.orderIdent INNER JOIN
    empCust ON 
    orders.custIdent = empCust.custIdent INNER JOIN
    product ON OrderItem.styleRef = product.styleRef  INNER JOIN
    productSize ON OrderItem.sizeChartIdent = productSize.sizeChartIdent 
WHERE empCust.custIdent = @custIdent
    and orderItemAudit.dateShipped >= @startDate
    and orderItemAudit.dateShipped <= @endDate
GROUP BY product.styleRef, product.styleDesc, empCust.custName, productSize.sizeChartNme
ORDER BY product.styleRef, product.styleDesc, empCust.custName, productSize.sizeChartNme
```

I don't understand this because that table IS in an INNER JOIN?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didnt add the column to the group by expression:

```
GROUP BY product.styleRef, product.styleDesc, empCust.custName, productSize.sizeChartNme, OrderItem.orderItemValue
```

Comment: Sorry Tejs, edited the wrong answer! My bad! I've rolled it back. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

When you do a `GROUP BY` you are saying "For all the rows that have the same values for these fields, show me some aggregation of the other fields".

When there is a field that is **NOT** in the `GROUP` then it needs to be either aggregated or excluded.

Basically each row of your result set could represent dozens or hundreds of rows of raw data, and SQL doesn't know which of these to select if you don't use aggregation.

That being said, if you add it to your `GROUP BY` list it should resolve the issue.  Alternatively, if the values should be the same for that field for all rows in a particular group, you can aggregate the field with something simple like a `MAX()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `OrderItem.orderItemValue` to your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
GROUP BY product.styleRef, 
         product.styleDesc, 
         empCust.custName, 
         productSize.sizeChartNme,
         OrderItem.orderItemValue
```

Comment: the only problem is when i do this, it doesn't seem to be giving me the results i want.

Comment: unsure of the results  you want.